# __init__.py :: make a submodule routines available at top level import

Tags: python, import, initialization, package

Assume the following structure...

```
root/test.py
root/myapp/__init__.py
root/myapp/myapp.py       # contains My_App_Class()
root/myapp/SomeObject.py  # contains My_Obj_Class()
```

If my `__init__.py` contains the following structure:

```
from myapp import *
import SomeObject

__all__ = ['SomeObject']
```

I want to be able to call `myapp` and have the routines pre-extracted from `myapp/myapp.py` so that I can do the following in `test.py`:

```
import myapp

if 'My_App_Class' in myapp.__dict__.keys():
    print 'success'
else:
    print 'fail'

if 'My_Obj_Class' in myapp.SomeObject.__dict__.keys():
    print 'success'
else:
    print 'fail'
```

so that I can effectively collapse `from myapp.myapp import *` into `from myapp import *`

```
In [1]: %run test.py
fail
success
```

Comment: It sounds like you're really resisting the Python module system. It sounds like what you need is one file, `myapp.py`, not lots of different modules. Packages and modules are for creating namespaces, and since you only want one you only need one module.

Comment: Similar examples are `from matplotlib import mpl`, `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. These share the same structure as above for their own reasons

Comment: have you tried doing in __init__.py: import myapp, SomeObject __all__=['myapp', 'SomeObject']

Comment: yes that doesn't work - just tried it

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane, Many packages fight Python's module system, and it's mostly painful when they do both on their end for maintenance and on the other end for debugging. Matplotlib fights it relatively little on the whole and has long since retired `matplotlib.mpl`. It has a very different and much nicer structure to work with.

Comment: You especially want to avoid modules named like `foo.foo`. It is confusing to read and, in Python 2, can be the source of bugs.

Comment: It's also best to avoid classes named like `foo.Bar.Bar`. The repeated name adds confusion and overall it implies things about file structure that apply in, say, Java, but not Python. It doesn't help, but only makes things a bit harder to keep straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__all__` attribute in your `__init__.py` file is what is preventing other names (imported from myapp/myapp.py) from being visible when using the `myapp` package.

Just don't use the `all` - and maybe, to avoid ambiguity, change the import written as:

```
from myapp import *
```

to

```
from .myapp import *
```

In other words, your  `__init__.py` file should be simply:

```
from .myapp import *
import SomeObject
```

and no other line.

Your `test.py` on the other hand if further incorrect - if it starts with `import myapp` , all of myapp/myapp.py's names will be in the `myapp` namespace. You should change that first line to be `from myapp import *` as you put further down in the question.

Mandatory note: You should avoid doing `import *` and variants in Python projects that import names from packages. Python programs and projects should always import individual names from packages/modules - with the name written explicitly, anyone reading your code will know exactly from were each function or class you use came from. Moreover, IDE's and other programming tools will be able to check for non-existing or inconsistent names and warn you.

However, note it is ok to use  `from module import *` inside  a package's `__init__.py` to get the names exposed (in the `__all__` export) in each of the package's modules into the package namespace itself - which is what you want.

Comment: It does work - I had evne just tested with Python 2.7 and Python3.

Comment: Thanks and good spot on the test case containing a bad artefact. That threw me off initially.